# Z3 - how to count matches?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a finite set of pairs of type (int a, int b). The exact values of the pairs are explicitly present in the knowledge base. For example it could be represented by a function (int a, int b) -> (bool exists) which is fully defined on a finite domain.

I would like to write a function f with signature (int b) -> (int count), representing the number of pairs containing the specified b value as its second member. I would like to do this in z3 python, though it would also be useful to know how to do this in the z3 language

For example, my pairs could be:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
```

then `f(0) = 1, f(1) = 3, f(2) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an odd thing to do in z3: If the exact values of the pairs are in your knowledge base, then why do you need an SMT solver? You can just search and count using your regular programming techniques, whichever language you are in.

But perhaps you have some other constraints that come into play, and want a generic answer. Here's how one would code this problem in z3py:

```py
from z3 import *

pairs = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)]

def count(snd):
    return sum([If(snd == p[1], 1, 0) for p in pairs])

s = Solver()
searchFor = Int('searchFor')
result    = Int('result')

s.add(Or(*[searchFor == d[0] for d in pairs]))
s.add(result == count(searchFor))

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print("f(" + str(m[searchFor]) + ") = " + str(m[result]))
    s.add(searchFor != m[searchFor])
```

When run, this prints:

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 3
f(2) = 1
```

as you predicted.

Again; if your pairs are exactly known (i.e., they are concrete numbers), don't use z3 for this problem: Simply write a program to count as needed. If the database values, however, are not necessarily concrete but have other constraints, then above would be the way to go.

To find out how this is coded in SMTLib (the native language z3 speaks), you can insert `print(s.sexpr())` in the program before the `while` loop starts. That's one way. Of course, if you were writing this by hand, you might want to code it differently in SMTLib; but I'd strongly recommend sticking to higher-level languages instead of SMTLib as it tends to be hard to read/write for anyone except machines.